# XPath 'starts-with' return nil, but the element present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have two types of `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`:

```
<td><a href="somelink?etc...">text</a></td>
```

and:

```
<a href="somelink?etc...">text</a> <!-- not wrapped in <td> tag -->
```

I need to extract links with `href` started with `somelink`. There can be more than one link in the fragment, and not all of them can have `somelink` in the `href` attribute.

I used this code:

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<td><a href="somelink?etc...">text</a></td>')
fragment.xpath('.//a[starts-with(@href, "somelink")]')
```

It works OK for the first type of fragment wrapped with the `<td>` tag, but when I run this function for the second type I get an empty array.

When I run `fragment.xpath('.//a')` for the second type I get all links in the array, but I still need to filter them by `href`.

Can somebody explain this strange behavior?

Comment: try without the dot : fragment.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "somelink")]')

Comment: @Jayvee nope (( Without dot it doesn't work even on first type (with <td> tag)